# scanf() doesn't work in if statment

Tags: c, scanf

I'm using repl.it to write C, but when I run it, the system skips the second scanf in the if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
  char services[40];
  loop: printf ("I can help you to do somethings(fibonacci number, pi, 
  x^y and exit)\n");
  scanf ("%s", &services);
  if (strncmp(servies, "fibonacci number"))
  {
    float n, first = 0, second = 1, terms = 1;
    printf ("please enter the terms:\n");
    scanf ("%f", &n);
    printf ("fibonacci number                    terms          golden 
    ratio\n");
    while (terms <= n)
    {
      terms = ++terms;
      printf ("%f%35f%10f\n", first, terms, first/second);
      terms = ++terms;
      printf ("%f%35f%10f\n",second, terms, first/second);
      first = first + second;
      second = first + second;
      goto loop;
    }
  }
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: `scanf ("%s", &services);` --> `scanf ("%s", services);`

Comment: You should get a compilation error for the `strncmp` line, pay attention to compiler output

Comment: `terms = ++terms;` causes undefined behaviour, I guess you meant `terms = terms + 1;`

Comment: I got to `loop:` and my eyes burst into flames. Sorry I can't read the rest.

Comment: You should use `strcmp()`. And you need to read the documentation of the function, it doesn't return `true` when the strings match, it returns `0`, so you have to write `if (strcmp(string1, string2) == 0)`

Comment: @M.M no errors from broken C89 compilers <3

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True, I didn't notice that string.h had failed to have been included

Comment: `terms = ++terms;` -> `++terms;`  No idea what the while loop is for since you goto out of it. This code is terrible.

Comment: The `goto loop;` from inside the `while` loop is pretty odd.  It means you never iterate more than once.  You should aim not to use `goto`.  There are occasions when it is appropriate; I'm fairly sure this isn't one of them.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't read the warnings, or use a broken C compiler. After fixing the typo and the strings... and the UBs:

```
some.c: In function ‘main’:
some.c:19:13: warning: operation on ‘terms’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
       terms = ++terms;
       ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
some.c:21:13: warning: operation on ‘terms’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
       terms = ++terms;
       ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
```

I have only one warning left:

```
some.c: In function ‘main’:
some.c:9:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strncmp’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   if (strncmp(services, "fibonacci number"))
       ^~~~~~~
```

Indeed, the implicit definition of `strncmp` is used. Had you `included <string.h>`:

```
some.c: In function ‘main’:
some.c:11:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘strncmp’
   if (strncmp(services, "fibonacci number"))
       ^~~~~~~
In file included from some.c:4:0:
/usr/include/string.h:143:12: note: declared here
 extern int strncmp (const char *__s1, const char *__s2, size_t __n)
            ^~~~~~~
```

Indeed, the 3rd argument, or the maximum length to compare, is missing, and garbage in - garbage out is what you get.

However, you don't need `strncmp`, as `strcmp` is enough here. And notice that it returns 0, which is a falsy value, when the strings **match**!

Thus:

```
if (strcmp(services, "fibonacci number") == 0)
```

But now, when you run the program, you will notice that it doesn't work either - when you type in `fibonacci number` in the prompt, nothing appears. It is because `%s` reads *a white-space delimited word*; so `services` will now contain only `"fibonacci"`! To fix this, use `%[^\n]` to match non-newline characters, along with specifying the maximum length explicitly:

```
scanf("%39[^\n]", services);
```

And then it works... for that part, as you'd now notice that `goto loop` is in a wrong place...

Comment: But after I fixed it,the while statement didn't work